# После переноса индекса Elasticsearch не находит данные из фильтра

Tags: elasticsearch

после переноса индекса с одного кластера в другой индекс не ищет данные по фильтру. Кол-во Lucene docs одинаковое  в  обеих индексах. Все индексы Health (green)
Перенос индекса

> curl -k  --user login:password --request POST
> "https://elastic.local/_reindex?pretty"   --header 'Content-Type:
> application/json' --data ' {"source": {"remote": {"host":
> "http://0.0.0.0:9200"},
> "index":"index-name"},"dest":{"index":"index-name-clone"}}'

На фото результат фильтра по id  оригинальный индекс
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Клонированный индекс
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]